# Laravel: selecting with conditions from Many-to-many relationships

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many laravel relationship for posts and topics:

- Posts belongstoMany Topics
- Topics belongstoMany Posts

I want to get posts with **id > 10** from **a certain topic**

The following code will get me all the posts from certain topic:

```
$topic = Topic::where('id',$topic_id)->get()->first();
$posts= $topic->post;
```

Now how to get posts with  **id > 10** ?

Models:

```
class Topic extends Eloquent{

    public function post()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany('post');
        }
    }

class Post extends Eloquent{

    public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Topic');
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
Topic::with(array('posts' => function($q)
{
    $q->where('id', '>', 10);

}))->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: sorry I replaced the id with the topic id but now I'm getting this error:
{"error":{"type":"BadMethodCallException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::posts()","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\-\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php","line":1657}}

Comment: It's calling the method you made.  Yours is `post()`, his is `posts()`.  It makes more sense as `posts()` so I'd change your function name in our `Topic` model to `posts()`.

Answer (score 4):

you should do like this

```
$topic = Topic::find($topic_id);   
$posts= $topic->posts()->where('id','>',10)->get();
```

or

```
$posts = Topic::find($topic_id)->posts()->where('id','>',10)->get();
```

hope this help

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply `Where` clause to `belongsToMany`

Here is where condition

```
$permissions = Role::with('getRolePermissions')->where('id', '=', Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id)->get()->toArray();
```

In this URL `getRolePermissions` is the model function, Inside it I have used the Many To Many relationship

```
public function getRolePermissions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission', 'permission_role');        

    }
```