# Laravel where condition for one item?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have `Products` table and `Categories` table.

Each of products may have one or more cateories. For this I created table: `products_caetgories`.

So, how I can to set `where` condition where `product_category` = 1?

I tried like as:

```
Product::with("categories")->where("product_category", 1)->get();
```

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745512/laravel-selecting-with-conditions-from-many-to-many-relationships might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

takle a look at [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

> you may use the whereHas and orWhereHas methods to put "where"
>   conditions on your has queries. These methods allow you to add
>   customized constraints to a relationship constraint, such as checking
>   the content of a comment:

```
Product::with("categories")->whereHas("categories", function($query){
 $query->where('id','=',1);
})->get();
```